# Launch child process as root (python, setuid, MacOS)

Tags: python, macos, root, setuid

How can I launch a child process that has root privileges?

I have a python program in MacOS that can do most of its operations as a normal user. But occasionally, triggered by some user interaction, it will need root permissions to preform a task.

For security reasons, I don't want the entire GUI app to be started and left running as root. I want only a child process with a very minimal subset of functions to run as root.

For UX reasons, I don't want to have to tell the user "Sorry, please restart this app as Administrator". I want to be able to have them stay in the GUI, get presented with a pop-up that says "Uh, you need root to do that. Please enter your password."

Of course, if my unprivileged python process attempts to become root with

```
setuid(0)
```

...then I just get a permissions error

```
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

What can I use as an alternate to `setuid()` so that I can launch a new child process on a MacOS system, after escalating privilege by getting authentication from the user in the GUI?

Comment: You could use `subprocess.check_exec("sudo .<program to run as root> <arg1> <arg2>...);`, but you'd have to figure out how to get `sudo` to accept the password you've gotten from your user, as it won't be able to itself ask your user for their password.

Comment: I think my app taking the user's password and passing it to the OS is a non-starter. I shouldn't know the user's password. I should ask the OS to get that.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to be able to have them stay in the GUI, get presented with a pop-up that says "Uh, you need root to do that. Please enter your password."

This is exactly what the MacOS Security API's [`AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1540038-authorizationexecutewithprivileg) function was created for.

You can call `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges()` directly with python's [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html).

For example, consider your parent script running as your normal, non-root user. If you try to just run `setuid(0)`, then it will fail with

```
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

Instead, let's create another script named `root_child.py`, which we'll execute as root with `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges()`

### Child (root_child.py)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":
   try:
      os.setuid(9)
      print( "I am root!" )
   except Exception as e:
      print( "I am not root :'(" )
```

### Parent (spawn_root.py)

We can execute the above `root_child.py` script as root from our non-root script `spawn_root.py`:

```
import sys, ctypes, struct
import ctypes.util
from ctypes import byref

# import some C libraries for interacting via ctypes with the MacOS API
libc = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(ctypes.util.find_library("c"))

# https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security
sec = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(ctypes.util.find_library("Security"))

kAuthorizationFlagDefaults = 0
auth = ctypes.c_void_p()
r_auth = byref(auth)
sec.AuthorizationCreate(None,None,kAuthorizationFlagDefaults,r_auth)

exe = [sys.executable,"root_child.py"]
args = (ctypes.c_char_p * len(exe))()
for i,arg in enumerate(exe[1:]):
    args[i] = arg.encode('utf8')

io = ctypes.c_void_p()

print( "running root_child.py")
err = sec.AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges(auth,exe[0].encode('utf8'),0,args,byref(io))
print( "err:|" +str(err)+ "|" )
print( "root_child.py executed!")
```

### Example Execution

Note that, because the credential challenge for `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges()` comes via the GUI, you *must* execute this from within the GUI. If you attempt to execute the above scripts, for example, over a SSH in a tty, you'll get an error `-60007`, which is [`errAuthorizationInteractionNotAllowed`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1540004-authorization_services_result_co/errauthorizationinteractionnotallowed) and means:

> The Security Server denied authorization because no user interaction is allowed.

```
user@host ~ % ./spawn_root.py 
running root_child.py
err:|-60007|
root_child.py executed!
user@host ~ %
```

However, if executed from the Terminal app in the GUI, then it prompts the user for their password.

[image: screenshot showing a pop-up window with title "Python wants to make changes" and a Username and Password field presented to the user in the GUI]

If the user successfully enters their credentials correctly, then the `root_child.py` script is executed with root privileges.

```
user@host ~ % ./spawn_root.py 
running root_child.py
err:|0|
root_child.py executed!
```

## Additional Information

### Security

Note that `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges()` has been deprecated by apple in-favor of an alternatve that requires you to pay them money. Unfortunately, there's some misinformation out there that `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges()` is a huge security hole. While it's true that using `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges()` *incorrectly* can cause security issues, **it is *not* inherently insecure** to use it.

Obviously, any time you run something as root, you need to be very careful!

`AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges()` is deprecated, but it *can* be used safely. But it can also be used unsafely!

It basically boils down to: do you actually know what you're running as root? If the script you're running as root is located in a Temp dir that has world-writeable permissions (as a *lot* of MacOS App installers have done historically), then any malicious process could gain root access.

To execute a process as root safely:

1. Make sure that the permissions on the process-to-be-launched are root:root 0400 (or writeable only by root)
2. Specify the absolute path to the process-to-be-launched, and don't allow any malicious modification of that path

### Further Reading

1. [`AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges()` Reference Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1540038-authorizationexecutewithprivileg)
2. https://github.com/cloudmatrix/esky/blob/master/esky/sudo/sudo_osx.py
3. https://github.com/BusKill/buskill-app/issues/14
4. https://www.jamf.com/blog/detecting-insecure-application-updates-on-macos/